# Application Remembers that Alt Key Was Pressed after Alt+Tab Away

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

When I use <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> to switch away from an application, then return to that application, the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key does not work on the first press. Here's how to reproduce

- Open Chrome and Notepad++
- Activate Notepad++ using any method you like
- <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> to activate Chrome
- <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> to activate Notepad++
- Press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key one time

The menu in Notepad++ is not activated.

This is reproducible for me using most applications. Notepad++ is the one that clued me in to what's happening, though. When I <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> away from Notepad++, I can see that the menu selectors (underlines) are visible. They remain visible even as the application is inactive and when I reactivate it. When I return to the app, the Alt key removes the menu selectors - the opposite of what I want it to do.

The only application where this doesn't happen, that I've tried so far, is SQL Server Management Studio (but I've only tried about a dozen). No matter how I activate and deactivate SSMS, the Alt key activates the menu on the first press.

It's easy to see that the menu selectors are being activated in Notepad++, but less easy in applications that use a RibbonUI, like Office. It doesn't show the Ribbon tooltips like pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> alone in the application, but the effect is the same. That is, when I return to the application, I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> twice to see the tooltips.

It seems like I'm activating the menu before leaving the application, but that's not quite right. It's some weird third state. All other keys except <kbd>Alt</kbd> work as expected. If I activate the menu in Notepad++, then press the down arrow key, the File menu expands. But if I <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> away from Notepad++, then reactivate, the down arrow moves the cursor down one row as expected. So it's not as if <kbd>Alt</kbd> is necessarily persisting such that a down arrow would still expand the menu.

I want to <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> away from Excel, <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> back to Excel, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and not have `AC` appear in the active cell.

Screen shots:
When Alt-tabbing from Notepad++, you can see the hotkeys are underlined in the menu

[image: Alt tab away from Notepadd++]

When Alt-tabbing from Excel, no tooltips are shown

[image: Alt tab away from Excel]

I can't show you how when I return to Excel and press Alt, nothing happens, because nothing happens. If you can think of a particular screen shot you'd like to see, I'll provide it.

Comment: This might sound silly, but have you tried to reproduce with a different keyboard?

Comment: @Edward No I hadn't thought of that. Thankfully I get the same result (because I love my keyboard and would cry if giving it up was the right answer).

Comment: I wonder if I could short circuit this somehow with AutoHotKey,

Comment: @dkusleika - My first guess is the "Key Down" event is caught by Excel but that the app switcher catches the "Key Up" so Excel never gets the memo.

Comment: My take on the issue is that this is unavoidable. Alt-down is sent to the application, then Tab-down gets handled by Windows and switches the focus away. Alt-up is never sent. The rest is just the internal bookkeeping of the application and how it handles the sequence of Alt-down/Focus-out/Focus-in.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. If I'm in Excel and hold down Alt (keydown, no keyup) I see the tooltips on the Ribbon. But if I Alt+Tab, no tooltips. If Excel was getting the keydown and nothing else, wouldn't the tooltips still appear? Also note that holding down Alt does not show the tooltips immediately. In Notepad++, the keydown activates the menu. In Chrome, keyup activates the menu. So maybe Office accounts for no keyup after a wait. Unfortunately, I'm just going to have to train myself to live with it. Shouldn't take more than a year or so.

Comment: Excel might be intelligent enough after a focus-out to undo the Alt-down. Notepad++ maybe not. From your testing it seems that most applications don't handle this case.

Comment: It's not reproducible for me at none of mentioned apps. all of them behavior in normal way. can you mention your windows versions etc ? mine is :`Windows 10 Enterprise` x64, `Version 1511`, `OS Build 10586.420` on `MSI CX61 2QC` laptop, keyboard `PC/AT Enhanced PS/2 keyboard (101/102=Keys)`.

Comment: Could someone post a screen shot? I cannot seem to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with Windows 10 Enterprise x64 version 1607 and notepad++.

Comment: Seen that on IntelliJ IDEA long time ago and it was a Java bug, then Oracle fixed it. So nothing to do with your scenario :(

Comment: I can reproduce it too. I have 2 programs on my computer that show the exact same behavior. Notepad++ and OpenMPT. It could be a bug in the MVC framework used by both applications. It happens on different systems on my end, both Windows 8 and Windows 10. I therefor consider that this is not solvable.

Comment: Its not ideal, but if you want to avoid it, press alt first, then release, then alt-tab.

Comment: why it's not reproducible for some of us? what is the difference? it would help solving

Comment: Test with classic Alt+Tab by holding left Alt, press and releasing right Alt (while holding left Alt yet), and then holding Tab and see if problem persists.

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise 1607 Build 14393.321 on. I7-6700T @2.8GHz, 16GB Ram. Microsoft Wireless Multimedia Keyboard 1.0, but I tried a stock HP keyboard with the same results.

Comment: In Excel going to N++, `Alt down, Tab down, right alt down, right alt up`. This puts the focus in N++ without ever releasing Alt or Tab.

Comment: In Excel going to N++, `Alt down, Right alt down, right alt up, tab down, tab up, Alt up` puts me in N++ as expected. When I go back to Excel, Alt works as it should (one press activates tooltips).

Comment: In Excel going to N++, `Alt down, Right alt down, right alt up` - same as last comment, but stopping before the tab. This activates the tooltips. If I do it really fast, the tooltips are activated really fast. Compared to just holding down Alt that makes the tooltips come up eventually. It appears Excel tooltips are activated by either `Alt up` or holding down Alt for some time.

Comment: @dkusleika by the term `classic Alt tab`, i mean the way apps showed as icons only, instead of Task View-like new `Alt Tab` dialog. (same as usual `Alt Tab` with one `right Alt down + up` between `Alt` and `Tab`). Actually the second scenario you mentioned. so is it work well?

Comment: As i can see, this issue occur for some people and for some others not. My guess is that it comes from a windows update. my windows version is `1511` and i don't have the issue, and it happens for others that their windows version is `1607` (strangely i can't update to `1607`, it says `the update is not applicable to your computer`). So, One testing option is roll backing to `1511`. removing `kb3176929` update. although you may left some other bugs, but it may help knowing the root of issue

Comment: When was the first time you noticed this?

Comment: I got a new PC with Win 10 and noticed it right away. I was on Win 7 prior to that. So, sadly, I can't say if a patch was the cause because I hadn't had Win 10 long enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open registry and go to the following key:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`
note that you must be in `Explorer` key and not in its sub trees.
create a new 32-bit DWORD value named `AltTabSettings` and set it to 1.
Sign out from your Windows 10 session and sign in again.

**Note**
you can roll back the changes by deleting new value you created.

Comment: Switching back to classic Alt+Tab behavior fixes the problem. It's a shame I have to make that choice, but it's better than not having the choice.

Answer (score 2):

My take on the issue is that this is unavoidable :

Alt-down is sent to the application, then Tab-down gets handled by Windows which
switches the focus away. The result is that Alt-up is never sent, so the
application menu stays int Alt-pressed mode.
When you now do Alt-Tab and give the application back the focus,
the first Alt you press just undoes the Menu mode.

The rest is just the internal bookkeeping of the application and how it handles the sequence of Alt-down/Focus-out/Focus-in.
Some applications might be intelligent enough to after a focus-out to undo the Alt-down. From your testing it seems that most applications don't handle this case.

This is the behavior that I observe on a new Windows 10 VM and also on my own computer,
so this problem is the default condition for Windows 10.
It seems like some people do not experience this problem, but the reason why it doesn't
happen on their computers is still unknown to me at this time.

Comment: I don't think so. it's related to OS. As questioner says in comments *If I'm in Excel and hold down Alt I see the tooltips. But if I Alt+Tab, no tooltips. If Excel was getting the keydown and nothing else, wouldn't the tooltips still appear?* this refutes your guess. Furthermore, some users don't have this problem. so it must be solvable.

Comment: that exact "most applications" don't have this issue on my windows 10 OS. so OS should handle this, regardless of application behavior.

Comment: no, even notepad++ works well after `Alt Tab` to it. it enables menu by one `Alt`.   i don't find even one app on my OS to reacts wrong to this scenario.

Comment: @Behroozfar: It seems from your answer that you are using the old Alt-Tab implementation from XP, and that explains the difference. That's not a solution for people who prefer the current version.

Comment: I don't use classic old `Alt Tab`. my current version is same as images of the question and does its job nicely.

Comment: @Behroozfar: Then you have something else different, but I don't think we will find it here by discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ use the `Alt` button for many shortcuts
like

**Alt-0                 Fold All**

**Alt-(1~8)             Collapse the Level (1~8)**

**Alt-Shift-0       Unfold All**

**Alt-Shift-(1~8)   Uncollapse the Level (1~8)** 
Hence notepad++ waits for you to press a key and interprets it as a shortcut.

you can disable the shortcuts with `Alt`

```
Settings -> Shortcut Mapper
```

Comment: The problem is the menu, not the shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Check your windows version at `Settings > System > About`

If your windows version is 1607, then rolling back to windows version 1511 may solve the problem.

To do this, open the Start screen or Start menu and select Settings. Navigate to `Update & security > Recovery`. Click or tap the `Get started` button under `Go back to an earlier build` to uninstall the current build of Windows 10 and go back to the one you were using previously.

then restart computer and test the issue again.

Comment: **NOTE** As Windows can get mandatory updates from Microsoft, the issue may return again after some days. Thus if this method can solve the issue, you must take some steps to prevent update.