# Windows 11 Alt tab keeps alt pressed

Tags: windows, google-chrome, microsoft-word

I'm on Windows 11 and when I alt tab between two windows I have an undesirable behaviour which is the following:
[image]

As you can see on top (this is after I changed between windows), you have the same behaviour as if i had pressed alt on its own. Which means if i wanna start typing it just randomly selects an option on top.

The same happens in Word, in outlook and in Chrome. The only annoying one is Word because for the others I just don't type straight after alt tabbing so it doesn't really matter that much.

I've searched and searched and searched for an answer but I seem to be the only one with this problem. Have I done something wrong? The laptop is pretty new, I don't think I have installed any weird stuff on it.

I have also tried this: [Application Remembers that Alt Key Was Pressed after Alt+Tab Away](https://superuser.com/questions/1131723/application-remembers-that-alt-key-was-pressed-after-alttab-away) but this doesn't work sadly

EDIT : I used another laptop for several months because it was annoying me and I just saw people answered. I restarted the other laptopt and it seems that Microsoft patched it because I don't have the problem anymore. If someone has the same problem, maybe just launch windows update since they have apparently patched it!

Comment: Not here on my own Windows 11 machines (Desktop and Laptop).    " The laptop is pretty new, " ......  Try updating all drivers with the manufacturer's Driver Update App. Be sure to update Video and Chipset drivers.

Comment: What happens when you use the on-screen keyboard to alt+tab? Do you happen to have sticky keys enabled? Normally if you just held alt, the window-switch ui stays open, so it sounds like something is sending an extra alt-press after you finish tabbing over.

Comment: In Word, those are Ribbon ToolTips. Another press of Alt should clear them, or Esc. I refuse to use Windows 11 until they finish it for public release. I would suggest posting this in the Microsoft Community Windows 11 user-to-user support forum. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_11 Also use Microsoft's feedback mechanism.

Comment: It's been mentioned on Microsoft's tech community (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-11/alt-tab-issue-alt-stays-active/m-p/3346669/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8dG9waWNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9ufEwyWjY4UTlLOUdKSDVGfDMzNDY2Njl8U1VCU0NSSVBUSU9OU3xoSw#M3681), but it hasn't received any really useful answers. Reverting to "Windows 10" mode via registry is an ugly looking solution :-/

Answer (score 2):

Similar issue discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows11/comments/qja5g8/alttab_workflow_issues_on_windows_11/)

**Method 1**

Try turning off ALL apps that register global keyboard hotkeys.

In my case, turning off [Powertoys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) and [QuickLook](https://github.com/QL-Win/QuickLook) solved the "Sticky Alt" issue.

**Method 2**

You can also try [ExplorerPatch](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher). After installing it, set the alt-tab switcher back to "Windows 10" mode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Turning off Powertoys resolved the problem for me. Thanks! I actually want to keep Powertoys active, so I tried disabling just the Keyboard Manager in Powertoys. That seemed to reduce the behaviour, but it still acts up every now and then. So, maybe I need to completely close Powertoys in the background to get this annoying bug out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

This just started happening to me after installing the application AltDrag and having it seeming to crash. So a "global hotkeys" issue as stated above by heruji. Just thought I'd add that this app could cause it for anyone troubleshooting.